# SQL Server 2008: Null Return in Dynamic XML Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, for-xml-path

I have a set of dynamic queries which return XML as varchars, see below.

Example query:

```
set @sqlstr = 'Select ''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>'' + ''<File_Name><Location>'' + (Select a,b,c from table for xml path(''Row'')) + </Location></File_name>'''

exec(@sqlstr)
```

This works a treat until the `select a,b,c ...` query is NULL. Then I don't receive the outside elements as you'd expect like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"><File_Name><Location><Row></Row></Location></File_name>
```

All I receive is `NULL`

After a bit of Googling I find the issue is the concatenation of NULL results is a complete NULL Result. However I cannot find one solution gives me what I'd expect to be the result.

I've tried (not to say I have tried correctly)

```
IsNull(Exec(@sqlstring),'*blank elements*')
xsnil (doesn't seem to work in dynamic queries)
@result = exec(@sqlstring) then isnull and select
```

Anyone have a better solution? (preferably small due to multiple such queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
set @sqlstr = 'Select ''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?><File_Name><Location>'' + (Select IsNull(a, '') as a, IsNull(b, '') as b,IsNull(c, '') as c from table for xml path(''Row'')) + </Location></File_name>'''

exec(@sqlstr)
```

Comment: That's my mistake, I did a,b,c for the example its actually * as its in some cases 20 fields. your answer will work and if there is not a shorter method then having to list each one then I will accept as an answer thank you

Comment: If there is a shorter way, let me know so I can learn too @LRiley

Comment: Will do i'll post whatever answer I find

Comment: Seems there are no other options Thanks